# problem in hashing password and compare passwords in c#

Tags: c#, authentication, logging, hash, argon2-ffi

I create sign Up form with username and pass then I hash password using Argon2 Algorithm .
this is code for hashing:

```
private byte[] CreateSalt()
        {
            var buffer = new byte[16];
            var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            rng.GetBytes(buffer);
            return buffer;
        }
        private byte[] HashPassword(string password, byte[] salt)
        {
            var argon2 = new Argon2id(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

            argon2.Salt = salt;
            argon2.DegreeOfParallelism = 4; // four cores
            argon2.Iterations = 4;
            argon2.MemorySize = 256 * 256;

            return argon2.GetBytes(16);
        }
```

then I store user name , password ,salt key ,in SQL server DB.

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.users (username,password,token) VALUES(@username,@password,@salt)", cn) ;

           
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Convert.ToBase64String(hash));
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salt",Convert.ToBase64String( salt));
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the problem when user log in i get the salt key that i have sored for this user and hashing it whith password but it give me different result not same hash password in DB

what is the error ??

I tried to chang type of  salt key field in DB

Comment: You've only shown us half of the code - we can't see where you're doing the check. Ideally, provide a [mcve] - I wouldn't *expect* the actual database part to be relevant (just keep the strings in memory) but you should check that too.

Comment: **FYI** you should consider to store all needed informations within the password string like: `<algorithm-name>:<iterations>:<salt-base64>:<passwordhash-base64>`.